# How to binding data dynamically in grid in angular

Tags: angularjs

How to binding data dynamically in grid in angular

I have a problem  preparing dynamic grid for angular using web api.initially I am preparing table heading from database table and table body from csv. In table heading table i have datatype for each field.

**how to bind**.

```
        .csv
        ========
        ADescription,AProdName,BarCode,BaseUnit,CategoryID,Description,IsNonInv,PCode,ProdName,Status
        arabic RRM Product 001 Description,Arabic RRM Product 001,Product Wise BarCode,Nos,Products Category,RRM Product 001 Description,Spares,,RRM Product 001,Active
        arabic RRM Product 001 Description,Arabic RRM Product 001,Product Wise BarCode,Nos,Products Category,RRM Product 001 Description,Spares,,RRM Product 001,Active

        Header Table
        =============
            ColumnName  DataType Mandatory Hidden ReadOnly ColSeq

        51  ADescription    text        0   0   0
        51  AProdName   text        0   0   0
        51  BarCode text    0       0   0
        51  BaseUnit    int     1   0   0
        51  CategoryID  int     1   0   0
        51  Description text        0   0   0
        51  IsNonInv    int     0   0   0
        51  PCode   text    0       0   0
        51  ProdName    text        1   0   0
        51  Status  int 0       0   0


  in table heading
======================
```

> in ng-repeater =import in DataSetHeader and bind import.ColumnName

```
in table body
================
```

> in tr ng-repeat =Grid in Dataset and in that td ng-repeat =import in DataSetHeader.

in puttype should come from import.DataType and bind the data

Answer (score 0):

It's not your first time, you can convert your .csv into JSON.

Here's an example:

```
//var csv is the CSV file with headers
function csvJSON(csv){

  var lines=csv.split("\n");

  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }

      result.push(obj);

  }

  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```

Later you can use the angularjs ng-repeat to do so.

In angular 1:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

Where value is your json...

Ref 1: http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript

Ref 2: https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat